# Мусорное значение в динамическом массиве в структуре. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Делаю вычисление факториала от 21 до 30.
Использую длинную арифметику.
Произведение длинного и короткого чисел - написал, работает.
Пытаюсь всё это довести до ума рекурсией, составил алгоритм, вроде всё верно, но на выходе получаю не значение, а мусор.
Не понимаю в чём дело. Много вопросов вставали пока писал программу, но все их смог самостоятельно решить, хоть было и трудно, но здесь понятия не имею как решить. Помогите пожалуйста. Подозреваю, что дело в указателях, но не знаю как исправить. Не могу затягивать, всё перерыл, закончить нужно как можно быстрее, по этому прошу помощи... :(

Делаю пошагово, поэтому пока отталкиваюсь от значения факториала 20 (**{ 0,0,0, 0,4,6, 6,7,1, 8,0,0, 2,0,9, 2,3,4, 2 }**), и прописал множитель только для 21 (**{ 1,2 }**).
Факториал от 0 до 12 - сделал через int, факториал от 13 до 20 сделал через double, думал потом объединить это всё, соответственно от 0 до 20 делать по простому, а дальше уже через произведение длинного и короткого.
Собственно в этом коде как раз от 21 до 30 делаю...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct Result
{
    int* res;
    int size;
};

struct FResult
{
    int* numb1;
    int* numb2;
    int size1;
    int size2;
    int number;
};

Result multiply(int number1[], int number2[], int size_number1,
                int size_number2)
{
    int length = size_number1 + size_number2 + 1;
    int* subresult = new int[length] {0, }, *result = new int[length] {0, };
    int integer = 0, PlusSubResLen = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < size_number2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size_number1; i++)
        {
            subresult[i + j] = (number1[i] * number2[j] + integer) % 10;
            //остаток
            integer = (number1[i] * number2[j] + integer) / 10;
            //целое, перенос
        }

        if (integer > 0) //последний знак
        {
            subresult[size_number1 + PlusSubResLen] =
                integer; //конечный символ в результе         <--- сдвиг
            PlusSubResLen++;
            integer = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= size_number1 + PlusSubResLen;
                i++) //сложение массивов
        {
            int temp = (result[i] + subresult[i] + integer) % 10;
            integer = (result[i] + subresult[i] + integer) / 10;
            result[i] = temp;
            subresult[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    int leadnull = -1;
    bool check = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //проверка на лидирующие нули
    {
        if (check == false)
        {
            if (result[i] == 0)
            {
                leadnull = i;
                check = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (result[i] != 0)
            {
                check = false;
            }
        }
    }

    length = leadnull; //перезадаю длинну, для очевидности
    int* finalresult = new int[length]; //создаю массив нужной длинны

    for (int i = 0; i < length;
            i++) //записываю данные во временный массив (по сути конечный)
    {
        finalresult[i] = result[i];
    }

    Result final;
    final.res = new int[length];
    final.res = finalresult;
    final.size = length;
    return final;
}

FResult factorial_21To30(FResult old_result)
{
    FResult final;

    if (old_result.number == 20)
    {
        int number1[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 6, 7, 1, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 2 }; //20!
        int number2[] = { 0, 2 }; //20
        final.numb1 = new int[19];
        final.numb1 = number1;
        final.numb2 = new int[2];
        final.numb2 = number2;
        final.size1 = 19;
        final.size2 = 2;
        final.number = 19; //предыдущий типо
    }
    else
    {
        int number2[] = { 1, 2 }; //времянка <------------------
        Result subfinal;
        subfinal = multiply(old_result.numb1, number2, old_result.size1, 2);
        // большое число, малое число, размер большого, размер малого
        final.numb1 = new int[subfinal.size];
        final.numb1 = subfinal.res;
        final.numb2 = new int[2];
        final.numb2 = number2; //<---
        final.size1 = subfinal.size;
        final.size2 = 2; //<----
        final.number = old_result.number - 1;
        final = factorial_21To30(final);
    }

    return final;
}

int main()
{
    FResult final;
    int number1[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 6, 7, 1, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 2 }; //20!      число записано наоборот
    int number2[] = { 0, 2 }; //20     число записано наоборот
    final.numb1 = new int[19];
    final.numb1 = number1;
    final.numb2 = new int[2];
    final.numb2 = number2;
    final.size1 = 19;
    final.size2 = 2;
    final.number =
        21;  // если 20, то факториал 20, если 21, то рекурсия и выводит факториал 21
    final = factorial_21To30(final);
    printf("Novaya stroka:\n");

    for (int i = final.size1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) //вывод результата
    {
        printf("%d", final.numb1[i]);
    }

    int number2_2[] = { 1, 2 };
    Result finalMult;
    finalMult = multiply(number1, number2_2, final.size1, final.size2);
    printf("\nNovaya stroka:\n");

    for (int i = finalMult.size - 1; i >= 0; i--) //вывод результата
    {
        printf("%d", finalMult.res[i]);
    }

    int s;
    scanf("%d", &s);
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если немного изменить **main** (выбрал факториал 20, т.е. должен вывестись факториал 20, без расчётов даже, не входя в рекурсию):

```
int main()
{
    FResult final;
    int number1[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 6, 7, 1, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 2 }; //20!      число записано наоборот
    int number2[] = { 0, 2 }; //20     число записано наоборот
    final.numb1 = new int[19];
    final.numb1 = number1;
    final.numb2 = new int[2];
    final.numb2 = number2;
    final.size1 = 19;
    final.size2 = 2;
    final.number =
        20;  // если 20, то факториал 20, если 21, то рекурсия и выводит факториал 21
    FResult final2;
    final2 = factorial_21To30(final);
    printf("Novaya stroka:\n");

    for (int i = final2.size1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) //вывод результата
    {
        final2.numb1[i] = factorial_21To30(final).numb1[i];
        printf("%d", final2.numb1[i]);
    }

    printf("\nNovaya stroka:\n");

    for (int i = final2.size1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) //вывод результата
    {
        printf("%d", final2.numb1[i]);
    }

    int s;
    scanf("%d", &s);
    return 0;
}
```

То получаю такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. по сути вывожу два раза один и тот же массив, а получаю разный результат...

Comment: Где-то забыли инициализацию?

Comment: А для чего вы делаете подряд `final.numb1 = new int[19]; final.numb1 = number1;`?

Comment: Вначале создаю массив final.numb1, затем присваиваю ему значения массива number1.

Comment: А вы не задавались вопросом, почему в обоих случаях стоит знак `=`? Вы думаете, что первое `=` работает не так, как второе?

Comment: Да, логично. Видимо я решил, что иначе не сработает.. Нахожусь в процессе изучения и вспоминания.. Видимо меня переклинило, и решил по аналогии с "int *subresult = new int[length] {0, }, *result = new int[length] {0, };" и "int *finalresult = new int[length];" сделать. Но так или иначе, закомментировав все те моменты, я не получил иного результата. Результат всё тот же = (

Comment: Дело в том, что копирование массива знаком `=` вовсе не происходит. Копируется лишь указатель на него.

Comment: Т.е. у меня проблема с тем, что я копирую указатель? Но получается где-то это не создало проблем, а вот тут: final = factorial_21To30(final); уже возникает проблема.. Как тогда быть?

Comment: Как мне передать значения массивов, а не их указатели? Из структуры. Числа из структуры передались нормально, но как я передам массивы? =\

Comment: @IgRRR Рекомендую использовать векторы вместо массивов, вот они будут копироваться с помощью `=`.

Comment: спасибо, завтра попробую!

Comment: Всем спасибо, задачу решил.

Answer (score 1):

Мусор потому что UB у вас происходит, как минимум здесь:

```
int length = size_number1 + size_number2 + 1;
int* subresult = new int[length] {0, }, *result = new int[length] {0, };
int integer = 0, PlusSubResLen = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < size_number2; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_number1; i++)
    {
        subresult[i + j] = (number1[i] * number2[j] + integer) % 10;
        //остаток
        integer = (number1[i] * number2[j] + integer) / 10;
        //целое, перенос
    }

    // ниже по коду вы будете выходить за границы массивов
    // если окажется что size_number1 + PlusSubResLen >= lenght,
    // это может произойти если size_number1 < size_number2
    // и если PlusSubResLen >= size_number2, то есть если
    // будет много переносов

    if (integer > 0) //последний знак
    {
        subresult[size_number1 + PlusSubResLen] =
            integer; //конечный символ в результе         <--- сдвиг
        PlusSubResLen++;
        integer = 0;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= size_number1 + PlusSubResLen;
            i++) //сложение массивов
    {
        // здесь вы бужете выходить за границы массивов
        // если окажется что size_number1 + PlusSubResLen >= lenght
        // 
        int temp = (result[i] + subresult[i] + integer) % 10;
        integer = (result[i] + subresult[i] + integer) / 10;
        result[i] = temp;
        subresult[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что здесь есть проблема? Мне казалось, что с PlusSubResLen и длинами массивов я учёл нужные моменты. И при проверке, в этой функции, произведений длинных на короткие числа - проблем не возникало. Все я конечно не проверял, но проверял 20, 21, 23 и какие-то мелкие, типо 7..

Comment: Представьте что у вас на каждой итерации `integer > 0`, то если `size_number1 <= size_number2`, окажестя что `PlusSubResLen >= size_number1`. В результате выход за пределы массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, раз вы уж пишете на C++, а не на C, имеет смысл перейти к идиоматичным для C++ структурам данных. Нужно не таскать с собой указатели и длину, лучше воспользоваться `std::vector` и не искать ошибки в ручном управлении памятью. В результате получится вот что:

`struct Result` уйдёт, вместо неё будет `vector<int>`.

`struct FResult` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
struct FResult
{
    vector<int> numb1;
    vector<int> numb2;
    int number;
};
```

Код

```
int* finalresult = new int[length]; //создаю массив нужной длинны

for (int i = 0; i < length;
        i++) //записываю данные во временный массив (по сути конечный)
{
    finalresult[i] = result[i];
}
```

превратится в

```
vector<int> finalresult(length);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    finalresult[i] = result[i];
}
```

и т. д.

При этом большая часть проблем с памятью должна уйти. Если останутся ещё проблемы, это скорее будут проблемы алгоритмического характера.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Мой мозг сегодня слишком долго кипел, не могу уже собраться, что-то адекватно воспринять и понять, завтра попробую переделать по Вашему предложению. А с передачей значений через функцию не должно быть проблем?

Comment: @IgRRR: Ну, если вы передаёте `vector` по значению, то он скопируется. А если по ссылке, то будет передан тот же самый объект. Выбирайте, как вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу сказать что это ответ, но в дополнении к вышесказанным комментариям, если так уж хочется скопировать значения одного массива в другой, то можно пройтись циклом присваивая каждому элементу назначаемого массива элемент другого, идентичного по номеру.

Еще  посмотрите внимательно на дебаге и создайте в этой проблемной строчке точку останова и вы увидите, что  элементы массива  **old_result.numb1** в

`subfinal = multiply(old_result.numb1, number2, old_result.size1, 2);`

всегда равны нулю, даже если я выставляю все элементы в массиве `int number1[]`отличные от нуля.  К тому же вы выделяете память под массивы и ее не используете.

Comment: была такая мысль, но как быть допустим, тут: final = factorial_21To30(final); ?